# Probability of losing the bet

Tags: probability

Consisting of five matches.
Each game, the probability of winning is 1/2
The probability of a draw is 1/6
The probability of losing is 1/3
After five matches, if you lose three times (or more) consecutively, you lose the bet
What is the probability you lose the bet

What i have tried is 1-binomcdf(5,1/3,2). I got 17/81 but that seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 3):

Write L for lose (an individual match), and N for don't lose. The probability of L is $1/3$, and the probability of N is $2/3$.

You lose the bet with the following patterns: LLL, NLLL, NNLLL, and LNLLL.
The probability of LLL is $(1/3)^3$, the probability of NLLL is $(2/3)(1/3)^3$, and so on. Add.

Comment: Shouldn't the winning cases also be included?

Comment: @MohamadMisto they are included. Winning is a form of not losing (D).

Comment: Ah sorry didnt notice that

Comment: The question is about losing the bet. But maybe your question is about for example my LLL. I could have broken that up into $4$ cases, LLLLL, LLLLN, LLLNL, and LLLNN. The sum of the probabilities will turn out to be $(1/3)^3$, but it is much more efficient to stop at LLL, for whatever happens next we will lose the bet.

Comment: @MohamadMisto: Thanks for the comment. I unwisely chose D for don't lose, forgetting that D is also the first letter of the word draw. Fixed.